# Python: How to separate a string into list using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, match

I have a string that I want to separate into 2 parts: date and description. I also want to store these parts into a list. Is there a way to do this in one step?

Here is what I have attempted to do:

```
a = "4/10/2015 Internet Banking INTERNET BILL PAY xxxxxxxx5023 HSBC FINANCE"

parts = re.findall(r'(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)\s(?P<description>.*)', a)
```

This returns the following:

```
[('4/10/2015', 'Internet Banking INTERNET BILL PAY xxxxxxxx5023 HSBC FINANCE')]
```

The result I want would be something like this:

```
['4/10/2015', 'Internet Banking INTERNET BILL PAY xxxxxxxx5023 HSBC FINANCE']
```

Comment: Where is the part where you try to make a list? What is your actual question?

Comment: For the given example you can use `a.split(' ', 1)`.

Comment: No idea what is wrong with this code. Also, see http://ideone.com/Z9NWkj. If there is just one search operation, it makes sense to use `re.search` and get the `groupdict()` since there are named capturing groups in the pattern. Do you expect only one match?

Comment: You're getting a list of tuples - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Thank you huck_cussler. Your solution works just great!

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant solution, but you can just:

```
list((re.findall(r'(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)\s(?P<description>.*)', a))[0])
```